# Vue 3 runtime bundle without initial component/render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to implement some vue components to existing page.

Vue comes with multiple bundles:

1. Runtime + Compiler
2. Runtime Only

Currently I use `Runtime + Compiler`

My `HTML` looks something like this:

```html
<div id="app">
    <h1>Some Text<h1>
    <p>Long Text</p>

    <v-component-table/>

    <p>Long Text</p>
    <p>Long Text</p>

    <v-other-component/>

    ...more normal HTML
</div>
```

JS

```js
import { ref, createApp, defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
import store from './store'

const app = createApp({

    setup(){

        const page = ref({})

        return { page }
    }
})

app.use(store)
app.component('v-component-table', defineAsyncComponent(() => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ '@components/VComponentTable')))
app.component('v-other-component', defineAsyncComponent(() => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ '@components/VOtherComponent')))

const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

Using above (with runtime + compiler) Vue will parse/compile everything inside `#app`.

When I tried to change to only `Runtime bundle`, this requires to create initial `render` component/function

```js
import App from 'App'
import { h } from 'vue'
import store from './store'

const app = createApp({

    render(){

        return h(App)
    }
})
```

Above replaces the current content inside `#app` (logical).

So my question is: it is possible to mount Vue, without initial `App` with only `Runtime Bundle`, or If I don't want a `compiler`, I need to create Vue Instance per component that I will use on page? (If I need to create Vue Instance per component how can I share `Vuex`, between this instances?)

Reason: The page is big, and I need to inject to this page 2-3 components of Vue. and want to avoid Vue parsing all the content inside `#app`

Comment: This is probably XY problem. If you need to render components as widgets on existing page, which is a common, case, don't mount it to #app. If you need to maintain a state that is common to widgets, mount the app to empty container, and make widgets teleports.

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask yes this exactly what I came up with and works perfectly and I can remove compiler from the bundle (The page seems renders faster as well) But this for Vue3, Vue2 doesn't have teleport I think.

Comment: 2 has portal plugin but IIRC it differs from teleports in some way.